# How to run nodejs script from windows file explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, node.js

How to make .js files runnable from windows file explorer and show console result?

I want js code run with nodejs and leave results on screen.
One way - to create file run.bat, which will run command

```
node test.js
pause
```

But it require to crate separate bat file for each program.

Second way - create file association .js files with node.exe
Then programs run on .js double click. But program result disappeard instantly.

How to run on double click, and keep terminal window to show result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file containing following:

```
node %1   
pause
```

preferably pin that bat file to taskbar, and drop the js file onto it anytime.

`%1` will contain the fullpath of .js file launched.

(note, you might need to put in quotes `"$1"` if calling from cmd)